# Mercury and 502 glue

Tags: safety

I do some experiments with liquid mercury and I use a special bottle that was 3d printed (ABS plastic). To prevent leaking of mercury I use 502 glue layered around the bottle.

I want to know, if it is safe to store mercury in this bottle?

Does mercury interact with something in 502 glue?

502 glue: Methylene Chloride , Ethyl acetate, Toluene, Cyclohexane

I am not a professional at chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

Mercury does not react with this compounds. However, I strongly encourage you to

1) use monolithic vial for mercury. 3d-printed pieces are very fragile in my experience. Glass vial should be fine, however I recommend double casing (keep sealed glass vial with mercury in a bigger plastic vial with sulfur dust.)

2) perform all operations with mercury over steel of plastic pan.

3) keep a piece of copper foil/plate and nitric acid at hand. Mercury drops stick to copper, freshly washed in nitric acid, which is used to collect mercury.

4) in case mercury is somewhere you don't have access to, drown it in concentrated iron (III) chloride solution. It will transform metallic mercury into mercury chloride, that does not give vapors.

5) Note, that mercury salts may react with some organic compounds, including aromatics (toluene). While risks are low, organomercury compounds accumulates in living tissues, so caution is required.

Answer (score 2):

Mercury does not react with these products.

Consider investing in a mercury spill kit if you can afford it, otherwise find some powdered sulfur and keep it in a safe place.  See http://www.epa.gov/hg/spills/